# How to remove particular mass action option from dropdown in Magento2

Tags: magento2

`Sales -> Orders -> Mass Action`
Here I want to remove the `Print Invoice` button from the drop-down.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `actionDisable` setting in your custom module, that should  disable the option in the dropdown:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Company/js/grid/massactions">
    <action name="enable">
        <settings>
            <actionDisable>true</actionDisable>
        </settings>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a simple module to remove Print Invoices action from the sales orders actions drop-down.

I am listing down the main steps. I assume that you already know the about required files to create a Magento 2 module working.

> **Step 1: Create a file `app/code/Stack/RuleBasedDiscount/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` and put the following code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" class="Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Ui\MassAction">
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

> **Step 2: Create the file `app/code/Stack/RuleBasedDiscount/Ui/MassAction.php` and put the following code:**

```
<?php
namespace Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Ui;

class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    private $authorization;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
            \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
            array $components,
            array $data
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepare() {
        parent::prepare();
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        //if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Catalog::the_acl_youd_like_to_use')) {
        $allowedActions = [];
        foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
            if ('pdfinvoices_order' != $action['type']) {
                $allowedActions[] = $action;
            }
        }
        $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;
        //}
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
    }
}
```

> Step 3: Run the following commands under document root:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: @amit-naraniwal, **`php bin/magento s:up`** is the shorthand for **`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: @amitnaraniwal, can you please upvote my answer if it helped?

Comment: Hello i have tried your all three steps but it nor wokring for me , my code in app/code folder , i am using magento 2.3

Comment: Here array needs to be added before "$components" variable in constructor, otherwise it will throw incorrect argument type error in code compilation.