# Magento2 remove Assign a Customer Group column from action dropdown

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, uicomponent, overriding

I want to remove **Assign a Customer Group** action from dropdown in customer grid but i cannot override it in custom module, can anyone let me know how to achieve it? i have tried by taking  node and removed that action from my custom module customer_listing.xml but it still displays that action.

[image: need to remove this action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Solution given below works magento opensource 2.3.3 and above (tested)`**

It will work, set `actionDisable` node to **true** to disable the MassAction from the dropdown list of actions

**`<actionDisable>true</actionDisable>`**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <settings>
                     <actionDisable>true</actionDisable>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**Update**

For versions below 2.3.3. use the one explained in the links below

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231723/695

https://webkul.com/blog/hide-mass-actions-based-on-some-conditions-in-magento-2/

Comment: it throws error:1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/html/ek/app/code/Expresskitchen/Ekprojects/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml" is invalid:
Element 'actionDisable': This element is not expected.
Line: 18

Comment: magento version ? i tested this on 2.3.3

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.1

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: thanks, this solution worked for me:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231723/695

Comment: great. am glad, its helpful !